# nonlinear for loop

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to create something like a for loop in MATLAB with a nonlinear interval i.e. log scale?  I know that I can just use a while loop, but I was wondering if there was something simple like a for loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
for ctr = logspace(1,10,100)
    disp(ctr)
end
```

The `for` loop variable can range over any array.  You could do:

```
x = [1 2 4 4 3 10];
for ctr = x
    disp(ctr)
end
```

as well.